# can't install package scrapy

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy

I got the following error. This is lxde system. Can anyone help?

```
(xenial)minkang@localhost:~$ pip3 install scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/minkang/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 12, in main
    from pip._internal.utils.entrypoints import _wrapper
  File "/home/minkang/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/minkang/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 58
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
```

Comment: You're using python 3.5, which doesn't have f-strings. It looks like pip may be misconfigured

Comment: I installed pip3, what should I do to configure pip?

Comment: you should install newer Python - ie. 3.8, 3.9

Comment: if you have newer Ubuntu which uses only Python3 then `pip` and `pip3` should be only aliases to the same program - you could rename `pip3` to `pip` or you could create link to have both `ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip`

Comment: first you should check if you have newer Python in `apt` - `apt search python3.9` - and install it. Newer version may have preinstalled `pip` (and `pip3.9`) specially for `Python3.9` or you can check in `apt` if there is `python3.9-pip`

Comment: if you don't have newer versions in `apt` then you can use unofficial repo with different Python versions for Ubuntu, Linux Mint and similar https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa